# jq error "object is not valid in a csv row"

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I'm using `jq` to convert a nested `.json` file to `.csv`, however, there seems to be an issue when I have a particular **key**, **value** within the **JSON**. The script I'm using comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748291/499581), which works if I eliminate one line from the input file.

**ERROR**:

```
jq: error (at example.json:0): object ({"favicon":...) is not valid in a csv row
```

The error message isn't very descriptive, since the object it mentions doesn't seem to be the culprit.

**json2csv.jq**

```
paths as $path
| {path: $path, value: getpath($path)}
| select(.value|type == "object" )
| select( [.value[]][0] | type != "object")
| .path + ([.value[]])
| @csv
```

**example.json** (which validates with https://jsonlint.com):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "title": "Title of Item",
      "internet": {
        "favicon": "https://example.com/icon.png",
        "domain": "https://example.com"
      },
      "image": {
        "gif": null,
        "main": "https://example.com/image_large.png"
      },
      "description": {
        "origin": null,
        "resource": null
      },
      "referral": {
        "owner": null,
        "name": null
      },
      "url": "https://example.com/image.png?version=1"
    }
  ],
  "other": {
    "data": 0,
    "notes": 1,
    "total": 1,
    "misc": 1
  }
}
```

Removing the following from the **JSON** doesn't throw error from `jq`:

```
, "url": "https://example.com/image.png?version=1"
```

**Invocation**:

```
$ jq -er -f json2csv.jq example.json
```

I can't really change the `.json` file, because it needs the problematic line, so I'm looking for a solution from `jq`.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines by describing and/or showing the expected output (preferably both).

Comment: @peak: Everything above is the example; output is not important, as I can adjust that as necessary. The error is the issue, without getting past that I have no output.

Comment: @peak: That worked! If you want to post that as an answer and why the other way failed I'll gladly accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `@tsv` and `@csv` require their inputs to be flat arrays (i.e., arrays of atomic values).  There are many (infinitely many?) ways to "flatten" objects and arrays, so without knowing something about what you expect, I'd just be guessing wildly.

If you want a wild guess, replace `.path + [.value[]]` by

```
.path + [.value[]|tostring]
```

At least that will always work (assuming the input is valid JSON) while producing easy-to-read results.